# Anyone know a Objective-C Stylus Parser?

Tags: objective-c, stylus

I´m coding a native objective-c app for my regularly webdev work. It´s a CSS editor that modifies the css source of a website in realtime as I type (no reload). That works actually. But I would like to use "Stylus" as input syntax and I need therefore a fast parser.

**So, does anyone know a objective-c port of stylus?**

I think I can always fallback to parse it via JS or node.js. 
But I think its not that fast?

Help would appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK, there aren't any ports of Stylus at all. There's a Ruby bridge so you can use it with Rails apps, but that just uses ExecJS to run the standard JavaScript implementation of Stylus. I would try using the JavaScript version before anything else, and then explore other options (which will be rather more labor-intensive) only if intractable performance problems crop up in actual use.